# Room cannot verify the data integrity, even after uninstalling app then re-installing

Tags: android, android-room, data-integrity

I have added some new Entities(tables) to existing database. So configured those in database configuration-

```
@Database(entities = {existingTable1.class, existingTable2.class, existingTable3.class, existingTable4.class,
        newTable1.class, newTable2.class
        }, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

Since, the app is in development stage I used to avoid migration. So I have unistall the app from device and install through Android Studio (Run). But its giving following error-

> Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed
>   schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix
>   this by increasing the version number.

In my manifest allowBackup is set to false as below-

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

> **EDITED**

I have one thing to mention. I have a sqlite database file in asset folder. I just copy it into corresponding app DB folder on installation. So when new table with lots of pre-populated data need to added, I just update that sqlite database file in asset folder, then adjust relevant entities and build/run the project. This way, it was working fine, but this time it is producing this issue.

Comment: Did you run atleast once after setting `android:allowBackup="false"` ?

Comment: make sure to clear data and cache

Comment: @ManoharReddy, yes. But after installing from the device, why this migration is required :O

Comment: @Sadat open app setting , clear data manually and check once .

Comment: @ManoharReddy, which "app setting"? would you please specify?

Comment: You app info  - > Storage -> Clear data

Comment: @ManoharReddy, I have did so, but no luck

Answer (score 4):

If you are prepackaging your database in your APK. Then delete 'room_master_table' from it.
You can [SQLborwser](http://www.sqlbrowser.com/) for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need data to save and don't care about them , just want to tell Room you are migrating you can use a `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` like this.

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        UsersDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
```

It will do the "uninstall" for you .

You can refer to [this article here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929)

Comment: I did this and I am still getting the error whats happening

Comment: increase room version. and use debug to show us the stack trace please

Comment: I was using an interger resource in a file called integers.xml like `R.integer.databaseVersion` that was the problem. Now that I am writing the interger directly it is working.

Answer (score 0):

When you change a Room database structure, you should create a way to update the existing database. If first structure was version 1, the second should be version 2.
But Room needs a way to update the existing database to the new structure.
You should create a migration function.

```
static RoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (RoomDatabase.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        RoomDatabase.class, "your_database")
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                        .build();                
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table...
    }
};
```

if you only want to start from the beginning without updating your current dabase, then you can delete it to force the database creation.

```
    static RoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (RoomDatabase.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                // do not forget to remove this line if it is not needed 
                context.getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("your_database");
                // Create database here 
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        RoomDatabase.class, "your_database")...
                ...
```

Comment: I have tried your second solution, but it just make the DB entries empty. I have edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: So, when you replace your DB with the one that is in asset folder, the issue persist?